# Is there a better way to add a new value/field for every key (sym) in a tibble instead of using mutate then pivot_longer?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have the following table and I would like to apply a function (ret) to the values BY sym. However, instead of creating a new column with that result (simple mutate), I would like to keep the table in long format and create a new row (field/value) for each day/sym.

```
x <- tibble(day=rep(1:5,2),
            sym=c(rep('a',5),rep('b',5)),
            field=rep('price',10),
            value=as.numeric(c(101:105,501:505))) %>% 
        arrange(day,sym)
```

```
> x
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     day sym   field value
   <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 a     price   101
 2     1 b     price   501
 3     2 a     price   102
 4     2 b     price   502
 5     3 a     price   103
 6     3 b     price   503
```

I can accomplish this task by mutate to create a new column and then pivot_longer and bind_rows but I have a feeling there is a more concise way...

Here is my solution:

```
ret <- function(x) c(NA,diff(x))/x
x2 <- x %>% group_by(sym) %>% mutate(ret=ret(value)) %>% 
    select(day,sym,ret) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols=c(-day,-sym),names_to='field',values_to='value') %>%
    bind_rows(x) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(day,sym,field)
```

```
> x2
# A tibble: 20 x 4
     day sym   field     value
   <int> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     1 a     price 101
 2     1 a     ret    NA
 3     1 b     price 501
 4     1 b     ret    NA
 5     2 a     price 102
 6     2 a     ret     0.00980
 7     2 b     price 502
 8     2 b     ret     0.00199
 9     3 a     price 103
10     3 a     ret     0.00971
11     3 b     price 503
12     3 b     ret     0.00199
```

Thank you!! Please let me know your thoughts

D

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `bind_rows` since you already have the `price` variable in the data.frame. If you rename `value` to `price` and don't remove it before pivoting, then you'll have both 'ret' and 'price' in your `field` variable without having to bind it back in:

```
x %>%
    group_by(sym) %>%
    mutate(ret = ret(value)) %>% 
    select(day, sym, ret, 'price' = value) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(-day, -sym),
                 names_to = 'field',
                 values_to = 'value')

# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   sym [2]
     day sym   field     value
   <int> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     1 a     ret    NA      
 2     1 a     price 101      
 3     1 b     ret    NA      
 4     1 b     price 501      
 5     2 a     ret     0.00980
 6     2 a     price 102      
 7     2 b     ret     0.00199
 8     2 b     price 502      
 9     3 a     ret     0.00971
10     3 a     price 103      
11     3 b     ret     0.00199
12     3 b     price 503      
13     4 a     ret     0.00962
14     4 a     price 104      
15     4 b     ret     0.00198
16     4 b     price 504      
17     5 a     ret     0.00952
18     5 a     price 105      
19     5 b     ret     0.00198
20     5 b     price 505
```

Comment: Thanks! That's better than what I'm doing... but I was still hoping for a solution that avoids pivot_longer altogether. For example, there could be more than just 'price' in the field column which I think breaks your solution.

Comment: @dave325 `tidyverse` is pretty opinionated, so I don't think you can do it that way with `tidyverse` functions. I'm sure there's a base R or `data.table` method for doing this without pivoting, but I'm not sure how much you'd gain.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  group_by(sym) %>%
  mutate(value=ret(value), field="ret") %>%
  full_join(x) %>%
  arrange(day,sym,field)
```

which returns

```r
Joining, by = c("day", "sym", "field", "value")
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   sym [2]
     day sym   field     value
   <int> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     1 a     price 101      
 2     1 a     ret    NA      
 3     1 b     price 501      
 4     1 b     ret    NA      
 5     2 a     price 102      
 6     2 a     ret     0.00980
 7     2 b     price 502      
 8     2 b     ret     0.00199
 9     3 a     price 103      
10     3 a     ret     0.00971
11     3 b     price 503      
12     3 b     ret     0.00199
13     4 a     price 104      
14     4 a     ret     0.00962
15     4 b     price 504      
16     4 b     ret     0.00198
17     5 a     price 105      
18     5 a     ret     0.00952
19     5 b     price 505      
20     5 b     ret     0.00198
```

Or replace the `full_join(x)` with `rbind(x)`.